# Draw points and lines in gnuplot

Tags: drawing, gnuplot, points

How is it possible with gnuplot to plot both isolated points and lines for the same input file?

I mean, once I have a file `data.dat` of this kind that defines two lines 1-2 and 3-4

```
x1 y1
x2 y2


x3 y3
x4 y4
```

I can plot the lines with

```
$> plot 'data.dat' w lp
```

but if I want to also add some isolated points to be displayed with gnuplot I would like to add to my `data.dat` file the following

```
x1 y1
x2 y2


x3 y3
x4 y4

x5 y5
x6 y6
x7 y7
```

obviously the points 5,6,7 are treated by gnuplot as points of a line. How can I draw 5,6,7 as isolated points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Organize your data in blocks. There should be exactly one empty line between two blocks:

  ```
  x1 y1
  x2 y2

  x3 y3
  x4 y4

  x5 y5
  x6 y6
  x7 y7
  ```
- Use `every` to specify which blocks of the datafile should be plotted. The syntax of every is described [here](http://lavica.fesb.hr/cgi-bin/info2html?(gnuplot)every) or in gnuplot (type `help every`)
- In your case you can then do the following

  ```
  plot "data.txt" every :::0::1 with lp, "" every :::2::2 with points
  ```

Answer (score 1):

if it's acceptable to plot point symbols for points 1..4, too, then just add empty lines after points 5 and 6 and say

```
plot "1.dat" with lines, "" with points
```

if not, I'd suggest writing the isolated points to a separate file.