# How to draw 2D diagram in linux

Tags: linux, gnuplot, diagram

I have a .txt file contatning points which is look like following:

```
##x1 y1 x2 y2
123 567 798 900
788 900 87  89
....
```

I want to draw 2D diagram which link each pair in line of the .txt file using gnuplot.

**Edit1:**

I find this [Draw points and lines in gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435684/draw-points-and-lines-in-gnuplot), but I don't know how to use gnuplot in my case.

**Edit2:**

There is no limit for the diagram type.
As I see [here](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/487/plot-your-graphs-with-command-line-gnuplot/) I could set terminal to png using following:

```
set terminal png
```

For line style I find this example [here](http://www.gnuplotting.org/plotting-data/):

```
set style line 1 lc rgb '#0060ad' lt 1 lw 2 pt 7 ps 1.5
```

and there is no need for lable for axes.

Comment: And would this diagram be a PDF, or a PNG, or a JPEG? What colour would the lines be? How thick should they be? Do the axes need labels? And finally, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have edit my question.

Comment: How many lines are there likely to be in the file - roughly? Do you know the maximum likely values for x and y - are all x and all y under 1000, maybe

Comment: See [Line segments using gnuplot](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31992684/2604213)

Comment: @MarkSetchell, number of line is 40331, and the max x is 54957 and y is 65534!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated**

In the light of your reply about the number of lines and the maximum x,y dimensions, my original, ImageMagick-based approach at the bottom of this answer is clearly NOT the right one for your specific problem. However, I will leave it for others to see as it would be perfectly fine for up to a few dozen lines. I am now providing a more appropriate `gnuplot` version.

**Gnuplot Version**

If you want to do it with `gnuplot`, it would look something like this:

```
set terminal png size 1000,1000
set output 'result.png'
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset border
plot 'lines.txt' using 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2) with vectors nohead notitle
```

If you save that in a file calle `plot.cmd`, you can then run it with

```
gnuplot < plot.cmd
```

[image]

If you want arrowheads, use a variant like this:

```
set terminal png size 1000,1000
set output 'result.png'
set style arrow 1 heads filled size screen 0.03,15,45 ls 1
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset border
plot 'lines.txt' using 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2) with vectors arrowstyle 1  notitle
```

[image]

**Magick++ and C++ Answer**

I decided to work out a Magick++ and C++ answer, just for fun. The code looks like this - and the command to compile is shown in the comments at the top.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// sample.cpp
// Mark Setchell
//
// ImageMagick Magick++ sample code
//
// Compile with:
// g++ sample.cpp -o sample $(Magick++-config --cppflags --cxxflags --ldflags --libs)
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <Magick++.h> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std; 
using namespace Magick; 

int main(int argc,char **argv) 
{ 
   InitializeMagick(*argv);

   // Create an image object, scaled by a factor of 100 to speed it up !
   float scale=100.0;
   Image image("650x650","white");

   // Construct drawing list 
   std::list<Magick::Drawable> drawList;

   // Initial settings, blue lines 1 pixel thick
   drawList.push_back(DrawableStrokeColor("blue"));
   drawList.push_back(DrawableStrokeWidth(1));

   // Read in lines from file, expected format "x1 y1 x2 y2"
   int lineno=0;
   std::ifstream infile("lines.txt");
   std::string line;
   while (std::getline(infile, line))
   {
      std::istringstream iss(line);
      int x1,y1,x2,y2;
      iss >> x1;
      iss >> y1;
      iss >> x2;
      iss >> y2;
      x1 = int(x1/scale);
      y1 = int(x2/scale);
      x2 = int(y1/scale);
      y2 = int(y2/scale);
      cout << "Line: " << ++lineno << " " << x1 << "," << y1 << " " << x2 << "," << y2 << endl;
      // Add this point to the list of lines to draw
      drawList.push_back(DrawableLine(x1,y1,x2,y2));
   }

   // Draw everything using completed drawing list 
   image.draw(drawList);

   // Write the image to a file 
   image.write( "result.png" ); 

   return 0; 
}
```

I generated 1,000 lines of random test data with Perl like this:

```
perl -E 'for($i=0;$i<1000;$i++){printf("%d %d %d %d\n",int rand 65000,int rand 65000, int rand 65000, int rand 65000);}' > lines.txt
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

**Original Answer**

You could also do it quite easily with ImageMagick which is already installed on most Linux distros anyway. There are actually only 4 lines of code in the following - the rest is all comments:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create the output image, 1000x1000 pixels say
convert -size 1000x1000 xc:pink result.png

# Suppressing lines that have a hash (#) at the start, read in the file "lines.txt"
grep -v "^#" lines.txt | while read x1 y1 x2 y2; do

   echo Read line $x1,$y1 $x2,$y2

   # Tell ImageMagick to draw the line on the image
   convert result.png -stroke blue -strokewidth 5 -draw "line $x1,$y1 $x2,$y2" result.png
done
```

[image]

**Output**

```
Read line 123,567 798,900
Read line 788,900 87,89
```

Comment: I want to show start and end of each line with circle or something else

Comment: Thanks for your update, how it would be in  ImageMagick ?

Comment: also How can I change coordinate in ImageMagick, (now is top,left corner and I want to be bottom,left)

Comment: The ImageMagick method I initially suggested loads the whole image in, draws a line on it and saves the whole image again for each and every line so it is not going to be good for 40,000 lines. For performance reasons, it would need to be done either in Perl, or PHP, or C++ with Magick++ which requires installation of Perl modules or PHP and libraries or a compiler so it is quite long-winded and relatively difficult if you don't know what you are doing - especially when you have a working `gnu plot` solution.

Comment: There is tutorial on Magick++ with C++ here... http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/tutorial/Magick++_tutorial.pdf and you would be looking at `DrawableLine()`.

Comment: You can flip the image at the end with ImageMagick to change the coordinates... `convert inputImage.png -flip outputImage.png` or `-flop` as you wish, or `-rotate 90` etc.

Comment: I added a C++/Magick++ version for fun.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using `rsvg-convert` (from librsvg) or `svg2png`. Both of those programs expect an inout file in SVG format and render it as a PNG file. So you would need to convert your

```
123 567 798 900
788 900 87  89
```

into this type of thing

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <line x1="123" y1="567" x2="798" y2="900" stroke="blue" stroke-width="1"/>
  <line x1="788" y1="900" x2="87" y2="89" stroke="blue" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg>
```

That can be done easily enough with a little `awk` script like this:

```
awk '
   BEGIN{ printf("<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" version=\"1.1\">\n") }

  {
     x1=$1; y1=$2; x2=$3; y2=$4;
     printf("<line x1=\"" x1 "\" y1=\"" y1 "\" x2=\"" x2 "\" y2=\"" y2 "\" stroke=\"blue\" stroke-width=\"1\"/>\n")
  }

  END{ printf("</svg>\n") }' points.txt
```

You can then pump the output of that into either of the two programs I mentioned above:

```
awk ... | rsvg-convert -b \#ffff00 > result.png
```

[image]