# What's the easiest way to draw line segments in order to visualize the output of some algorithm?

Tags: c++, windows, image, bitmap, draw

I want to draw (dashed) line segments in order to visualize the output of some algorithm. How can I do this?

I know that this question is a bit vague, but I'm open to any kind of visualization method which is easy to use.

Comment: You can use the Windows API (GDI) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for writing an SVG file - it is just text - [example here](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_stroking.asp) and then use ImageMagick to convert that to a PNG or GIF file with

```
convert dottedline.svg image.gif
```

ImageMagick is installed on most Linux distros and is available for free for OSX and Windows.

You could also use Magick++, the C++ library of ImageMagick, or `gnuplot` - see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33688740/2836621).

Comment: EPS is also text but far less verbose than SVG so much closer to what is being asked.