# Computationally Fast Way to Save Matlab Figures as Image (eg PNG)

Tags: matlab, performance, matlab-figure

I have a program that creates a lot of plots which I want to save as `fig001, fig002, ...`. At the moment, the only way I can do this is to either save them one by one as I go along using `print()` or so save them into a graphics object `FIG`.

Unfortunately, I have to create the plots sequentially (can't parallelise it). If I save as I go, then this takes quite a long time; if I store in `FIG` then do a `parfor`-loop over all the figures, then this is faster. However, it's still pretty slow, and it's a major bottleneck in my code.

Matlab is automatically writing a `1200x900` pixel image. In reality, it's just a graph with some (horizontal) straight lines on it. I really do not need a high image quality whatsoever; maybe reducing this would help speed things up? I can't find how to do this either.

I've had a look online, in particular at other SE questions, but I haven't been able to come up with a solution. There's various stuff about "playing around with the `hardcore` function". I'm a mathematician who wants a code to get some intuition for the problem; I'm not a proper programmer! As such, "play around with a function" (that might cause Matlab to crash) is rather difficult for me!

---

I've sorted this by using the Matlab `movie` function. Thank you Cecilia for your assistance!

Comment: If you are just interested in a few points on a graph which define a line, you could save those point coordinates in a text file. Then you can use the file to quickly reproduce the graph.

Comment: So yes, I do only have a few points, but I really want to generate them into graphs that I can save as, say, `.png` files. The reason for this is that I then want to make a 'slideshow' from the graphs (eg, using FFMPEG).

Comment: To answer your question about changing the image resolution: [Save Figure at Specific Size and Resolution](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/save-figure-at-specific-size-and-resolution.html)

Comment: @Cecilia I was more thinking a specific pixel size, but upon further looking I think I can just say '-r100' and this gives me `800x600` files. On testing, these are written much faster than the `1200x900` files, but not really any faster than even `40x30`. It's still a lot slower than I'd like... :/

Comment: Have you considered making a 4D matrix and saving it as a .avi or an animated gif to display your slideshow?

Comment: Erm, no, I haven't... because I unfortunately don't know anything about that at all! The documentation for Matlab's "movie" is most confusing (to me at least)!

Comment: I would suggest making your update about how to space the frames in the movie into a new question. It's not really related to saving images quickly.

Comment: Fair point. I'll do that in the morning =P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your intention is to use the images in a slideshow. I would suggest making a movie and using that instead. I've run a few tests, and saving a movie is much faster than saving individual pngs. I see about a 5x speed up in my simple test.

```
numImages = 25;

%Saving one figure at a time
tic;
for i= 1:numImages
    x = 0:0.1:2*pi;
    y = i*sin(x);    
    plot(x, y);

    fig = gcf;
    print('img.png', '-dpng', '-r50'); %Downsample resolution
end
toc;

tic;

%Saving a movie
v = VideoWriter('mov.avi');
open(v);
for i = 1:numImages
    x = 0:0.1:2*pi;
    y = i*sin(x);
    plot(x, y);

    drawnow; %Force the figure to render
    frame = getframe; %Convert the figure to a movie frame
    writeVideo(v, frame); %Write the frame to the movie file
end
close(v);

toc;
```

Using writeVideo also has the advantage of never storing the whole movie in memory. Instead, as each frame is captured, it is immediately written to the file. The one downside is that because the frames need to be written in the correct sequence, you can not use a `parfor`

You could also consider making a movie matrix. Each element would be a frame. So to initialize the size of the matrix, you would need something like

```
numImages = 25;
mov(numImages) = struct('cdata',[],'colormap',[]);
```

Then using the `parfor`, you can assign all the images to your `mov` matrix in the correct order. After your loop is finished, you can write the movie to a file using `VideoWriter`. However, while generating your figures, you will need to keep your whole movie in memory, and there is an overhead associated with `parfor`, so it may not end up being more efficient.

Comment: Let me know if you need more details about making the movie.

Comment: Just adding to Cecilia, the reason for this is based on the number of files it creates. Unfortunately it takes a fair amount of time for matlab to open a file then close it. This is why videos are significantly faster (only one file to open and close) than a sequence of images.

Comment: @DanielAldrich This is the issue I was finding, ie that the overhead on `print` is so large.

Comment: @Cecilia Thanks for that. Would it potentially be better to instead of saying `frame = getframe` and then adding that frame to the end of the video (I assume `writeVideo(v, frame)` concatenates `v` and `frame`?), to do a `parfor` loop and save `F(i) = getframe`, then say `v = movie(F)`?

Comment: So, I've got a movie out of it, thank you. There are a couple of things that I'd like to improve though. Since "comments are not for extended discussion", I'll edit the original question to include these.

Answer (score 1):

If you made **Matlab** output a file like this, called "lines.txt" with each line describing the x1,y1 and x2,y2 of a line on your output image:

```
10 100 600 100
50 400 800 400
100 820 350 820
```

Then you could use **ImageMagick** to draw the lines like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create the output image, 1200x900
convert -size 1200x900 xc:gray80 result.png

# Loop, reading one line at a time from the file "lines.txt"
while read x1 y1 x2 y2; do

   echo Read line $x1,$y1 $x2,$y2

   # Tell ImageMagick to draw the line on the image
   convert result.png -stroke blue -strokewidth 5 -draw "line $x1,$y1 $x2,$y2" result.png
done < lines.txt
```

[image]

Obviously, you can draw non-horizontal lines and you could output a colour after the x,y coordinates and/or a thickness...

**ImageMagick** is installed on most Linux distros and is available for OSX and Windows. There are more efficient ways of plotting the lines, but this may be plenty to get you started.

Another option may be to use **Gnuplot**, see my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33688740/2836621).

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going to try the `movie` option first, but if I can't get that to work, then I'll have a look at yours! :)

Answer (score 1):

On top of Cecilia's answer which suggests using `getframe` to generate a movie, I'd like to add that `getframe` can also be used to improve speed for saving static images. Combine it with `frame2im` to convert the figure into a rasterized image, and then use `imwrite` to save the rasterized image to a file.

```
frame = getframe(fig); % fig is the figure handle to save
[raster, raster_map] = frame2im(frame); % raster is the rasterized image, raster_map is the colormap
if isempty(raster_map)
    imwrite(raster, fig_file);
else
    imwrite(raster, raster_map, fig_file); % fig_file is the path to the image
end
```

In my particular case the time used to save the figures is reduced from ~60s for 19 files (using `saveas`) down to 7~9s using this method.

Do note that this method

1. Does not change the background color to white as `saveas` does;
2. Does not seem to support resolution and dpi other than that of the current figure;
3. Does not support saving as a vector image (obviously).

Comment: Interesting, thank you! Could be very helpful, speeding up the saving :)